# Quadratic Form - find a minimal scalar $m \in \Bbb R$ such that $q(x,y,z) \le m(x^2+y^2+z^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

> Let $q (x,y,z)$ be a quadratic form, $$q(x,y,z)=2zx+4yz-2xy $$   $$V=\Bbb R^3$$
>
> Find a minimal scalar $m \in \Bbb R$ such that $$q(x,y,z) \le m(x^2+y^2+z^2)$$ for all $x,y,z \in \Bbb R$.

Actually I don't where to start. How do I find such a scalar?

Comment: I'm confused: most bilinear forms I have encountered take two vectors as input.

Comment: @B.Pasternak, this person regularly writes quadratic forms and bilinear forms without distinction.

Comment: @WillJagy I'm sorry for the confusion. I'm not an English native speaker. I understand from your comment it is a quadratic form?

Comment: It is; it's the quadratic form coming from the bilinear form $B(v,w)=v^TGv$, where $G$ is some (symmetric) matrix.

Comment: @WillJagy How curious that you have this knowledge, he must be really persistent with this inconsistency.

Comment: @B.Pasternak, I did not know ahead of time, I checked his past questions in his profile page, just before typing that comment.

Comment: I have typed in what I think is a responsible method for finding the Gram matrix $G.$ I do not think it difficult, if you will just write out the calculation I indicate, compare with your $q(x,y,z).$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will follow your guidelines. – Alan just now   edit

Comment: @B.Pasternak Now *I'm* confused. Shouldn't there be a $w$ on the right hand side of your equation?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Yes yes I was trying to edit, but the time had gone by. I'm really glad you caught it! Saves the OP some confusion probably, if he reads it.

Answer (score 1):

to start, find the Gram matrix $G$ for the quadratic form, which is $1/2$ the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives of $q.$ The result is that, when we have a column vector 
$$ v = 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{array}
\right)
  $$
with row vector $v^T,$ then we get
$$ q(v) = v^T G v $$

extreme behavior comparison with the identity form, occurs at eigenvectors of $G.$

So, maybe you know partial derivatives or maybe you don't, find symmetric matrix $G$ such that $ q(v) = v^T G v $

If you have not had partials, write
$$ G = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & f & e \\
f & b & d \\
e & d & c
\end{array}
\right)
  $$
then write out $v^T G v $ in symbols, and adjust $a,b,c,d,e,f$ to make it all fit your $q(x,y,z)=2zx+4yz-2xy $

EDIT: I once taught linear algebra out of *Elementary Linear Algebra with Applications* by Anton and Rorres (1987). Theorem 1 on page 345 is proved on pages 348-349. I will give the version for a three by three real symmetric matrix $G:$ Let $$ \lambda_1 \leq  \lambda_2 \leq \lambda_3 $$ be the eigenvalues of $G.$ Then
$$ \color{blue}{\lambda_1 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \leq \; \; v^T G v \; \; \leq  \lambda_3 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)} $$
Equality, on either side, can occur only at the relevant eigenvector.
 Their proof does not use calculus (Lagrange multipliers), instead it is essentially that real quadratic forms (real symmetric matrices) can be orthogonally diagonalized.

For our exercise, $\lambda_1 < 0$ while $\lambda_3 > 0.$

Hmmm. I think I taught out of that book; I have a copy. It was a long time ago, though, not sure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will follow your guidelines.

Comment: yes I believe I have to solve this with orthogonal diagonalization . That's the way my professor wants. Thank you!